# Logging the error received in SSIS Execute Process task

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, ssis

Is there a way to log the error received in the SSIS Execute Process task? I'm only receiving the return code:

> the process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0"

I'm running a several step batch job that returns this error and I need to debug it. It runs perfectly when ran directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the batch file logging. Use the `Batch file name` in the Executable and `>>1.txt` in Arguments. You don't need to worry about the space issue as it will overwrite the file each time.